# Ruby on rails, stream single console output to multiple clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been working with actionController::live and streaming linux console applications to my webclient.

I'm trying to build my own wifi router interface to display things like wifi signal, download speeds and some authentication with wpa_supplicant

I'm using the basic example you would find in the documentation for the actioncontroller::live and a little bit of jquery to update a div on the client side.

from my controller I can do something like this to simulate a wifi signal stregth progressbar.

```
Loop do
   Response.stream.write(File.read('/proc/net/wireless'))
End
```

With a little math can easily display a live stream of wifi strength in the form of a progress bar...

So, there is not much of a issue here until I run a system command.

```
stream.write(`ping googleDOTcom`.each_line{|line| p line+'<br>') }
```

if multiple web clients view this stream, the controller would start multiple processes...

2 issues I hope to discuss options or solutions... how could I start a application like `ping GOOGLE` and have multiple webclients view the same stream. Also how can I do this by only starting one instance of the `ping GOOGLE`

your comments are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that instead of this being a controller action you turn it into a model action. Then take the results and try to save them in the database as an attribute.

You could probably generalize the check a bit to allow the user to specify the end host to ping against. Then you should look into Active Jobs. I'd schedule a regular interval job that will instantiate a check based on the model id and save the results to the DB. Users are simply viewing the results of these scheduled checks.

It would certainly cut down on the work your server is doing and would prevent someone from exploiting a long running command to muck with your service.

Comment: I was working on examples last night with sqlite. I created a table of ping(pid, TEXT). then on the client side select * from ping, could perform checks if the process already exist and display text or each line of the application.  You suggest model action? maybe a small example you might have? in my mind I can only come up with hacky solutions.

Comment: I'd create a model named something like ping_check and maybe attributes: 'remote', 'count', 'results'. Then the model  could have: `def execute #write execute here end`. Then active job would take the ping_check instance and execute `ping_check_instance.execute` and it would save the results back to the model.